# The 5 types of joins in SQL

Tags: sql

Here is an image of the data set > [image]

I was asked to perform a select * statement on the two tables, and write down the result for all 5 kinds of joins.

So basically:

```
select * from table_a a left join table_b b on a.column_a = b.column_b
```

For this I answered: `1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 null`

Can somebody tell me if the answer is wrong/right?

Also, can you please list down the output for all 5 types of joins (left, right, inner outer, cross) for this? With a good explanation

Comment: Who said there's "5 types of joins"? There's (_at least_) `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, `FULL OUTER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT ANTI-JOIN`, `RIGHT ANTI-JOIN`, `LEFT SEMIJOIN`, `RIGHT SEMIJOIN`, `ANTI-SEMIJOIN`  and I think Relational Division probably counts too. (I'll admit that I only learned about some of these joint types just now, lol)

Comment: Sadly your answer is incorrect. For an example: https://dbfiddle.uk/YX6SSLKr

Comment: For each entry `a` in `A`, you will have two rows of `{a, a}`. So 10 rows overall of `{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}, ...`. Note that `NULL = NULL` is not true, and matches nothing at all. However, it is a `LEFT JOIN`, so because it matches nothing, you'll have a final row of `{null, null}`.

Comment: I think you dodged a bullet, figuring out all the combos for 5 joins would take forever for any normal human being

Comment: @Dai the question was about SQL language and not a theorical one. In SQL there is 8 type of joins : INNER, LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER, FULL OUTER, CROSS JOIN, UNION JOIN, LATERAL ... JOIN and PARTITION ... JOIN...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is the result set from that query needs *two columns*.

Otherwise, this dataset is a poor choice for demonstrating the JOIN types, because there are no values that are unique to A and B, such that the OUTER join types will always closely resemble the INNER join types. Really, the *only* difference for the INNER join is excluding the `null` rows, because `null` is never equal to itself. You might also change the ordering of the sets for left vs right, but without an  `ORDER BY` clause the order is meaningless and you are free to write the results in whatever order you want... and many databases will often silently rewrite RIGHT JOIN as the equivalent LEFT JOIN and give you the results as if you'd written it that way in the first place... ordering and all.

They could fix the data set by adding one row with a `2` value to either the A or the B table (but NOT both), and one row with a `3` value to the other table.

Finally, if I were to list the five basic join types, I would write: "left, right, inner, cross, and full". I would NOT list "outer", because its already implied as part of left, right, and full, and repeating it as separate join type, after already showing examples for left and right, makes no sense. More recently I might also include a sixth LATERAL type (APPLY in SQL Server).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Do you, however, think this is an ideal question to evaluate someone's SQL skills? I felt totally dumb and clueless and usually have no problems while solving complex problems. This question however left me all embarrassed. Worst interview I could've had, till date.

Comment: "I might also include a sixth LATERAL type" those can also be CROSS or OUTER so two more not one more.

Comment: @frub I feel the question generally is fair, but (as the middle paragraph explains) the data set choice was poor.